# 私は or この手紙は that means I wrote this letter

Tags: particle-は, word-order

‎What is the difference between

> 私はあなたの鉛筆でこの手紙を書きました。

and

> この手紙はあなたの鉛筆で書きました。

Do the two sentences have the same meaning?  I'm trying to say:

> I wrote this letter with your pen.

Comment: You tagged this 'passive voice', but you don't mention the passive voice anywhere in your question.  It looks like your question is actually about topicalization.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically the same meaning. They both mean "I wrote this letter with your pencil" (not pen).

> 私はあなたの鉛筆でこの手紙を書きました。

This one has "I" at the beginning.

> この手紙はあなたの鉛筆で書きました。

This one doesn't have "I". That's ok. You can often leave out 私は in Japanese because it's clear from context. The other difference is, 手紙 became the topic of the sentence, so its particle を changed to は.